# How to execute '<(cat fileA fileB)' using python?

Tags: python, shell

I am writing a python program that uses other software. I was able to pass the command using `subprocess.popen`. I am facing a new problem: I need to concatenate multiples files as two 
files and use them as the input for the external program. The command line looks like this:

`extersoftware --fq --f <(cat fileA_1 fileB_1) <(cat fileA_2 fileB_2)`

I cannot use `shell=True` because there are other commands I need to pass by variables, such as `--fq`.(They are not limited to --fq, here is just an example)

One possible solution is to generate middle file.
This is what I have tried:

```
file_1 = ['cat', 'fileA_1', 'fileB_1']
p1 = Popen(file_1, stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(['>', 'output_file'], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)

p1.stdout.close()
output = p2.communicate()
print output
```

I got error message: `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` Which part did I do wrong?

It would be better if there is no middle file. For this reason, I am looking at named pipe. I do not quiet understand it.

I have looked at multiple questions that have been answered here. To me they are all some how different from my question here.
Thanks ahead for all your help.

Comment: What makes you think that `--fq` is incompatible with `shell=True`?

Comment: Hi Rob, maybe I did not say it clearly. User may specify if they want `--fq` or not, which means there are some commands that are not passed to external software.In another example, user should be able to specify the amount of threads they want to use. The program should pass variable to external software. Using `shell = True` require passing a string and shell will execute the string exactly the way it is written. I will lose the ability to pass variables with `shell = True`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way bash handles `<(..)` is to:

1. Create a pipe
2. Fork a command that writes to the write end
3. Substitute the `<(..)` for /dev/fd/N where N is the input end file descriptor of the pipe (try `echo <(true)`).
4. Run the command

The command will then open `/dev/fd/N`, and the OS will cause that to duplicate the inherited read end of the pipe.

We can do the same thing in Python:

```
import subprocess                                                            
import os                                                                    

# Open a pipe and run a command that writes to the write end                 
input_fd, output_fd = os.pipe()                                              
subprocess.Popen(["cat", "foo.txt", "bar.txt"], shell=False, stdout=output_fd)
os.close(output_fd);                                                         

# Run a command that uses /dev/fd/* to read from the read end                
proc = subprocess.Popen(["wc", "/dev/fd/" + str(input_fd)],                  
                        shell=False, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)               

# Read that command's output                                                 
print proc.communicate()[0]
```

For example:

```
$ cat foo.txt 
Hello

$ cat bar.txt 
World

$ wc <(cat foo.txt bar.txt)
      2       2      12 /dev/fd/63

$ python test.py
      2       2      12 /dev/fd/4
```

Answer (score 1):

Process substitution returns the device filename that is being used. You will have to assign the pipe to a higher FD (e.g. 20) by passing a function to `preexec_fn` that uses `os.dup2()` to copy it, and then pass the FD device filename (e.g. `/dev/fd/20`) as one of the arguments of the call.

```
def assignfd(fd, handle):
  def assign():
    os.dup2(handle, fd)
  return assign

 ...
p2 = Popen(['cat', '/dev/fd/20'], preexec_fn=assignfd(20, p1.stdout.fileno()))
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, we may use:

```
import subprocess
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_fd1, output_fd1 = os.pipe()
    subprocess.Popen(['cat', 'fileA_1', 'fileB_1'],
     shell=False, stdout=output_fd1)
    os.close(output_fd1)

    input_fd2, output_fd2 = os.pipe();
    subprocess.Popen(['cat', 'fileA_2', 'fileB_2'],
     shell=False, stdout=output_fd2)
    os.close(output_fd2)

    proc = subprocess.Popen(['extersoftware','--fq', '--f',
     '/dev/fd/'+str(input_fd1), '/dev/fd/' + str(input_fd2)], shell=False)
```

Change log:

Reformatted the code so it should be easier to read now (and hopefully still syntactically correct). It's tested in Python 2.6.6 on Scientific Linux 6.5 and everything looks fine.

Removed unnecessary semicolons.

Comment: Hi @guoc, thank you for your answer. I am wondering does python require `;` at the end of a sentence? I am writing in python 2.7.8 and I have never wrote a `;` before. Thank you. :)

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the confusion. Semicolons are not required in any version of Python. It's not necessary to put a semicolon to terminate a statement unless you want to put multiple statements in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually possible have it both ways -- using a shell, while passing a list of arguments through unambiguously in a way that doesn't allow them to be shell-parsed.

Use `bash` explicitly rather than `shell=True` to ensure that you have support for `<()`, and use `"$@"` to refer to the additional argv array elements, like so:

```
subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c',
    'extersoftware "$@" --f <(cat fileA_1 fileB_1) <(cat fileA_2 fileB_2)',
    "_",    # this is a dummy passed in as argv[0] of the interpreter
    "--fq", # this is substituted into the shell by the "$@"
])
```

If you wanted to independently pass in all three arrays -- extra arguments, and the exact filenames to be passed to each `cat` instance:

```
BASH_SCRIPT=r'''
declare -a filelist1=( )

filelist1_len=$1; shift
while (( filelist1_len-- > 0 )); do
  filelist1+=( "$1" ); shift
done

filelist2_len=$1; shift
while (( filelist2_len-- > 0 )); do
  filelist2+=( "$1" ); shift
done

extersoftware "$@" --f <(cat "${filelist1[@]}") <(cat "${filelist2[@]}")
'''
subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', BASH_SCRIPT, '' +
    [str(len(filelist1))] + filelist1 +
    [str(len(filelist2))] + filelist2 +
    ["--fq"],
])
```

You could put more interesting logic in the embedded shell script as well, were you so inclined.